# Installation Error! The package already exists

Tags: android

When I try to run `google-play-services_lib` on my `samsung galaxy s3 phone`, I get this error:

```
"Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.  You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING:  This will remove all application data.  Do you want to uninstall?"
```

I click YES and then this shows up in the console:

```
"[2013-09-05 01:53:01 - google-play-services_lib] Installation error! The package already exists.
[2013-09-05 01:53:01 - google-play-services_lib] Launch canceled!"
```

Here is the full console log, from the time I hit "run".

```
"[2013-09-05 01:51:49 - google-play-services_lib] Performing sync
[2013-09-05 01:51:49 - google-play-services_lib] Uploading google-play-services_lib.apk onto device 'd20eb13c'
[2013-09-05 01:51:49 - google-play-services_lib] Installing google-play-services_lib.apk...
[2013-09-05 01:53:01 - google-play-services_lib] Installation error! The package already exists.
[2013-09-05 01:53:01 - google-play-services_lib] Launch canceled!"
```

I don't know what to do to fix this problem.  I tried searching online and people say uninstalling the app on my phone would help, but I don't think the app is on my phone.

Comment: uninstall and reinstall the app must be on the phone cross check again

Comment: This is what I'm doing to cross check:

press home button, hit menu, select 'settings', select 'application manager', starts in 'downloaded' tab, scroll down to g's, i see 'google play store', 'google search', and 'google+'.

Those are the only three... and none of those are google-play-services_lib right?

What should the name of the app be on my phone if it indeed exists?

Comment: I have a feeling this may have something to do with the virtual devices?  Although I went to run configurations and made sure to let me choose devices before running, and I always choose my phone.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to uninstall application from device using command.

Just use PACKGE_NAME= app package name which you are trying to install

for windows execute in cmd

```
YOUR_PATH\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb uninstall PACKAGE_NAME
```

for linux execute in terminal

```
YOUR_PATH\android-sdk\platform-tools>./adb uninstall PACKAGE_NAME
```

hope this will help.

Comment: The error says [2013-09-05 01:51:22 - google-play-services_lib] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.google.android.gms' in a shell. So I went to

Comment: The error says [2013-09-05 01:51:22 - google-play-services_lib] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.google.android.gms' in a shell. So I went to

c:\program files (x86)\android\sdk\platform-tools> directory and typed 

adb uninstall com.google.android.gms

is that what i'm supposed to do?  

I did it but it gave me "failure"

Comment: Thank you very much for that tip, I tried it but I got a failure message :(

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to run `google-play-services_lib` on your device? Are you developing an app which references the Google Play Services SDK?

The Google Developers page may point you in the right direction: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: yes I am trying to run the sample for the Google Maps Android API according to these instructions:

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html

however when I run it I get this error:

[2013-09-05 01:51:22 - google-play-services_lib] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.google.android.gms' in a shell.

So I did what it told me to do, but the command line says:

"Failure."  So now I'm really stuck!

Comment: You only need to _reference_ that library in your project, [http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject). If you have Google Play installed on your device, then you have the library, and you don't have to worry about installing it :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a 3rd party firmware image? The preinstalled google-play-services_lib might be signed differently from the standard one on the google play store.

If the pre-installed apk is signed with non-google standard keystore, and since it is preinstalled in the system partion, the uninstallation action will fail. You cannot update it in a normal way.

Try to root your device and replace all the GMS packages with standard release.

Comment: Thanks for the advice... how do I root my device and replace all the .gms packages with standard release?

Comment: To root your device, you can google your device model with keyworad root and you will find the solution easily. And the standard GMS packge, you shall go to your manufacturer's web site to download the official released firmware image and extract it to get the GMS apks. And if you have difficulty on this, still try to google GMS for 4.x.x and you can find it.

Comment: Thank you!!  I successfully rooted my device, but now I have one more question:  what exactly am I trying to download (the firmware image)?  I googled "GMS for 4.1.2" but to no avail.  Could you tell me specifically what I need to download?

Answer (score 0):

A Much easier solution to this problem is bij renaming the application package after Uninstalling.

1. Right click on your project.
2. Android Tools => Rename Application Package
3. rename => finish

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the folder containing you apk from command prompt ie adb shell.

   a. adb remount -rw

   b. adb shell su -c setenforce 0

   c. adb shell rm /system/priv-app/[your apk]

   d. adb uninstall [package-name]

   e. adb reboot
2. Now install through eclipse.

Worked for me :)